# Foursquare Real-Time API. push-notifications

Tags: foursquare

I have a problem with Foursquare Real-Time API. push-notifications stopped coming 
When I send a test push-notifications I get an answer: The request timed out (or your push address is invalid)

With the push url okay.
The problem started 2-3 days ago, before everything worked steadily. 
How can I solve this problem? I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We're currently looking into an issue with the push API and hope to have it fixed very soon. For the latest, you should follow [@foursquareAPI](https://twitter.com/foursquareapi)